# mt.exe -replacements: xml file structure for registration free COM component is not documented

Tags: com, mt, registration-free-com

I am using *mt.exe* to generate a manifest for a registry free C++ COM component. The .rgs file passed on the command line has some replaceable strings whose value must be stored in a .xml file passed to the `-replacements` argument. The thing is, there is no documentation on the expected syntax for that xml file. I reported the issue to Microsoft but the [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/555109/mtexe-replacements-file-format-is-not-documented.html) was closed without providing any solution. Does any one know how the replacement xml file should be structured?